# Possibly GCC bug on for with two variables compilation

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc

I'd faced some strange GCC behavior on this code compilation:

```
for(int i = 9, j = 0; i >= 0; --i, j++) {
    cout << i << " " << j << endl;
}
```

Obviously, **i** here is pre-incremental, and **j** is post-incremental and in first iteration **i** should be 8, and **j** should be 0, but it seems that GCC treats both **i** and **j** as post-(dec/inc)remental.

So I'm getting output

```
9 0
8 1
...
```

GCC 1.9.3 PAE,  compiled with -O0

Comment: The last part of the `for` statement [`for(initialise,condition,this_bit_after)`] is executed after the content of the loop block, so yes, they're both post-incremented with regard to the body of the loop.

Comment: "GCC bug" is a big thing to say, especially for a this common piece of code. Triple check the problem and the code before. 99.999% of problems are NOT compiler bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working as expected.

The iteration expression is executed at the end of the loop body. The `while` loop equivalent for your code would be something like this:

```
{
    int i = 9, j = 0;

    while (i >= 0) {
        cout << i << " " << j << endl;
        --i, j++;
    }
}
```

Notice that the pre- and post-increment are functionally equivalent in this case.

You are assuming that the expansion is something like this:

```
{
    int i = 9, j = 0;

    while (i >= 0) {
        --i;
        cout << i << " " << j << endl;
        j++;
    }
}
```

But that is not how `for` loops work in C++.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, for some reason it wasn't obvious for me O_O

Answer (score 1):

Don't blame the compiler unless you really know what's going on.

```
for(int i = 9, j = 0; i >= 0; --i, j++) {
    cout << i << " " << j << endl;
}
```

is the same as

```
for(int i = 9, j = 0; i >= 0; ) {
    cout << i << " " << j << endl;
    --i;j++;
}
```

and NOT

```
for(int i = 9, j = 0; i >= 0;) {
    --i;
    cout << i << " " << j << endl;
    j++;
}
```

Prefix/Postfix is only important as part of some "normal" longer statement, but not loops.